# Please explain final AtomicReference

Tags: java, final, java.util.concurrent, atomicreference

can someone explain me this:

```
final AtomicReference<Integer> atomicReference = new AtomicReference<>(1);
atomicReference.set(2);
```

In what sense is final used?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> In what sense is final used?

The variable itself is final. You can't change the variable's value to refer to a different  `AtomicReference` object.

Calling `set` on the object and thus changing the data *within* the object isn't the same thing at all.

To put it in more real world terms, I can give you my home address and say, "You can't change where I live." That doesn't stop you from painting my front door green though (i.e. making a change to the house that the address refers to.)

Answer (score 2):

`final` prevents you from changing the *variable* to refer to a different instance.
It does not prevent you from *mutating* the existing instance.

It means that you can't write

```
atomicReference = something;
```

Answer (score 1):

`final` means that `atomicReference` can **not** reference another `AtomicReference` anymore.

Answer (score 1):

`final` just means that the variable/object cannot be reassign.

But you can modify your object through setter for example

Check it out:

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_(Java)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_%28Java%29)